# Water not draining

Tags: bathroom

We are having our bathtub converted to a tiled shower. After running the water for the first time, I noticed the water is puddling and not completely draining. The drain is at the front. Is there an easy fix for this, or is it major? I have not completely paid my contractor, and would like to know asap.

Comment: The difficulty of the fix is kind of irrelevant, as the contractor should be the one to remedy the issue.

Comment: it probably just needs shimmed up a bit, but that might force you to re-caulk and or re-tile if it's more than a minor adjustment.

Comment: And we can't help not knowing anything about your shower or plumbing. You'll need to provide _much_ more detail and/or photos if you'd like help. I agree, though. This isn't your problem to solve.

Answer (score 2):

If the water is puddling in a corner away from the drain, then the shower base has not been laid level.

Get them to re-lay it before you pay them.